# Searching an SQL Server database with Substring

Tags: t-sql, search, substring

I have a query that extracts only two columns and trims one of the columns to only the media name.  This is the query for that:

```
   Select
   [Object],  
   CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms,35,6) END AS [MEDIA]
   from JnlDataSection
```

The results from this is:

```
Object
---------
061 STATEMENTS

MEDIA
---------
X01180
X01181
```

As you can see there are multiple medias for one object.  What I want is a manual query in which I can just modify it with the object name and search one object with all of its respective medias and vice versa.

This is the query I came up with:

```
  Select
  [Object],  
  CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms,35,6) END AS [MEDIA]
  WHERE [OBJECT] = '061 STATEMENTS'
  from JnlDataSection
```

However I am receiving this error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
```

Please Note: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

**UPDATE**

After reading comments, I tried this query:

```
Select
  [Object],  
  CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms,35,6) END AS [MEDIA]
 from JnlDataSection
 WHERE [MEDIA] = 'X05219'
```

It gave me this error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'MEDIA'.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The order of clauses needs to be `SELECT...FROM...WHERE...GROUP BY...HAVING...ORDER BY`.  You have your `WHERE` before your `FROM`.

Comment: Select
  [Object],  
  CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms,35,6) END AS [MEDIA]
 from JnlDataSection
 WHERE [MEDIA] = 'X05219'

Comment: @JNK I get this error when I try to run this.  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'MEDIA'.

Comment: Because you can't filter on a case expression that you define in the `SELECT`.  You need to either reproduce the case in the `WHERE` or redefine it in a table expression or `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: @JNK How would that look like if I were to reproduce it in the WHERE?

Comment: `WHERE CASE <your case logic> END = 'X05219'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on [@JNK's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655323/searching-an-sql-server-database-with-substring/17660624#comment25713150_17655323), if you want to compare against the calculated `MEDIA` column, here are your options:

1. Reproduce the `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause:

   ```
   SELECT
     [Object],  
     CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms, 35, 6) END AS [MEDIA]
   FROM JnlDataSection
   WHERE CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms, 35, 6) END = 'X05219'
   ;
   ```
2. Redefine the query as a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

   ```
   WITH JnlDataSectionMedia AS (
     SELECT
       [Object],  
       CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms, 35, 6) END AS [MEDIA]
     FROM JnlDataSection
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM JnlDataSectionMedia
   WHERE [MEDIA] = 'X05219'
   ;
   ```

   or a (normal) subselect:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM (
     SELECT
       [Object],  
       CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms, 35, 6) END AS [MEDIA]
     FROM JnlDataSection
   ) AS s
   WHERE [MEDIA] = 'X05219'
   ;
   ```
3. Use [`CROSS APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx):

   ```
   SELECT
     j.[Object],
     x.[MEDIA]
   FROM JnlDataSection AS j
   CROSS APPLY (
     SELECT CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms, 35, 6) END
   ) AS x ([MEDIA])
   WHERE x.[MEDIA] = 'X05219'
   ;
   ```
4. You can also define your query as a [view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx):

   ```
   CREATE VIEW JnlDataSectionMedia
   AS
   SELECT
     [Object],  
     CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms, 35, 6) END AS [MEDIA]
   FROM JnlDataSection
   ;
   ```

   After that, you can call it at any time like this:

   ```
   SELECT [Object], [MEDIA]
   FROM JnlDataSectionMedia
   ;
   ```

   You can filter on either of the columns too, when necessary:

   ```
   SELECT [Object], [MEDIA]
   FROM JnlDataSectionMedia
   WHERE [MEDIA] = 'X05219'
   ;
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have solved this issue.  I am having trouble with something else regarding this same query, if you could take a look please.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658995/output-of-empty-columns-in-sql-query