# Output of Empty Columns in SQL Query

Tags: sql, database, output

I have a fairly large SQL Query that converts a numeric date data type to a date time value and further specifies the search based on my requirements. However when I run this query I'm seeing the column names but there is no data in the columns, it is just the titles of the columns in this order: Dataset, Date, Time, MsgID, Parms, Dataset
When the order should be: Data, Time, Dataset, Media (Separate column with Substring of Parms).  Also this is only showing my data from the past 2 days instead of the entire database, which also is a problem.

I need some help in displaying the columns in that order with the data present from all of the columns.  If anyone can make any suggestions or modificiations to my existing SQL query to get the required output, it would be greatly appreciated.  I know this is a quick fix for an expert programmer, but I'm still learning the ropes and require some assistance.

This is my SQL Query:

```
    SELECT [Object] AS [Dataset],
    CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS DATE) 'Date',
    LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS TIME),8) 'Time',
    MsgId,
    Parms,
    CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms,35,6)
    ELSE '' --Optional ELSE
    END  AS [Dataset]
    FROM ( SELECT  ItemId,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
    [Object],
    MsgID,
    Parms
    FROM JnlDataSection
    WHERE CAST(substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 0, 5) + '-' +
    substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 5, 2) + '-' +
    substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 7, 2) AS DATETIME) =
    CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))) A --Converting to date again to          remove     the time part
    WHERE SUBSTRING(Parms,35,6) = 'X05219' AS [Media]
    ORDER BY [DATE] DESC;
```

Please Note: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Comment: try running it without the `Where` clause, if you're getting results it's the condition...

Comment: @milenpavlov the absolute last where clause?

Comment: I'd comment the entire lot: `WHERE CAST(substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 0, 5) + '-' +
    substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 5, 2) + '-' +
    substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 7, 2) AS DATETIME) =
    CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))) A --Converting to date again to          remove     the time part
    WHERE SUBSTRING(Parms,35,6) = 'X05219' AS [Media]`     to see if that would make a difference..

Comment: @milenpavlov I did that and it is showing results, but the Parms is not trimmed anymore and msgid = 61 is not anywhere.

Comment: @milenpavlov it gives me this error when i comment that entire lot: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near 'JnlDataSection'.

Comment: Wouldn't your like be much simpler if you just stored dates using the datetime data type? Yes you'd have to update your table once, but I cannot imagine it not being worth it in the long run? A simpler solution would be to add a computed column in the datetime format that converted your int to a date, so you only need to bother with that horrendous casting and substrings once?

Comment: @GarethD the database was created several years ago and we don't have the authority to alter the database since so many users are on it at once.  instead we must resort to these long queries.

Comment: @omarK: You could create a view in that table and return normal `datetime` values in the view. That way it would be much easier to work with your data.

Answer (score -1):

Now, it looks like your extraction from [DATE] into Date and Time is incorrect. You are putting the same string into 'Date' and 'Time'

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me the correct syntax in my sql query?

Comment: I don't know the source of your data, nor what you are parsing into the Date and Time string.  If you look at what you are calling "Date", it is using the same subtstring that you are using for time.  My guess would be a different part of the DATE string, and also be using "/" instead of ":" as seperators.